# i am trying to use geoplugin in my nuxt 3 project but i couldn't find any solution

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, geolocation

```
server/api/geolocation.js
import { createError, send } from 'h3';

export default async (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']?.split(',').shift() || req.socket?.remoteAddress;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=${ip}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        send(res, 200, data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in geolocation API:", error);
        send(res, 500, createError({ statusCode: 500, statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error' }));
    }
};
```

this is my code where i am using the geolocation by middleware approach

my vue component where i want to use the geoplugin

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const geolocation = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/geolocation');
    geolocation.value = await response.json();
    console.log(geolocation.value); // Log the response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching geolocation data:', error);
  }
});

</script>
```

`<span v-if="geolocation && geolocation.geoplugin_countryName === 'United Kingdom'"><img></span>` but the image is not showing either its uk ip address or not